# nginx configuration of the upstream servers

Tags: nginx, load-balancing

I am trying to configure nginx with the upstreams.
Config we want to have :

- 1 load balancer (nginx)
- 2 web servers (nginx + php-fpm)

What do I need to configure in the web servers to "recognize" that they are part of this network ?

In the load balancer, if the upstream module in the nginx config looks like this :

```
upstream appcluster {
server host1.example.com:8080;
server host2.example.com:8080;
}
```

does it mean that the web servers have to be setup with individual subdomains ? and that the same site has to be hosted at these 2 subdomain locations ?

is it possible to not use subdomains ?

Answer (score 1):

When you use upstreams for php-fpm only (application servers), you don't need subdomains at all, just use IPs (internal adresses, not public)

```
upstream appcluster {
    server 172.31.235.101:9000;
    server 172.31.235.102:9000;
}
```

Comment: thanks Aleksey, so this is where I'm stuck too. How do I set up my web servers so that they know they're in the same network as the load balancer (as these are internal IPs) ?

Comment: Yes, you need assign IP from internal (local) network to all servers.

Comment: do I do that within nginx ? or outside ?

Comment: this is network interfaces issue, not nginx, but i'm not expert in the IP settings area, something like: http://www.unix.com/debian/222183-how-change-local-ip-address.html